# WPF ListView Nested Tables with Matching Columns

Tags: wpf, listview, nested, listviewitem, master-detail

I have a business entity like so:

```
public class Entity
{
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
    public Entity Parent;
    public ObservableCollection<Entity> Children
}
```

I would like to bind a ListView to a collection of Enities and get a nested table out of it like this:

http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/listview-masterdetail/

however I would like the nested table (which has the same columns as its parent) to position and resize its columns the same as the parent table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to check if treeview would work for you; there are ways of making it multi column (TreeListView). Check if example here: [TreeListView Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771523.aspx) would work for you. Should be looking like a control on the picture below:

[image]

source code for the control on the picture you can find [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeListView.aspx)